# no changes detected при миграции

Tags: mysql, python, django

Доброго времени суток всем!

Прошу помощи. Пытаюсь создать миграцию (`python manage.py makemigrations`), а он мне отвечает:

> ```
> no changes detected
> ```

Как быть?
Что я уже пробовал и не получилось:

1. Проверял есть ли в списке `installed_apps` в `settings`.
2. Пытался через `python manage.py makemigrations YOUR_APP_NAME`
3. Пересоздавал проект :)))

Прошу помочь, ибо устал уже.

P.S. Некоторые говорят, что надо удалить БД, но я слишком зеленый и не особо понимаю как, зачем и почему.

Comment: Папка `migrations` в директории приложения есть?

Comment: А изменения-то у вас вообще есть? Покажите, для чего вы хотите создать миграцию

Answer (score 1):

1. удаляете/комментируете приложение в installed_apps
2. удаляете папку migrations в папке вашего приложения
3. удаляете в БД все таблицы приложения app
4. удаляете все записи о приложении app из таблицы django_migrations
5. installed_apps -> uncomment app
6. python manage migrate app
7. profit